# joomla integration with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, joomla

I have one website with Joomla 2.5.
 I have another application which was written by asp.net and c#. I need that users who register in Joomla website can login to asp.net application with same username and password.
 I need when users want to login to asp.net application, my application connect to Joomla database (user table) and check their username and password.
 I don't know how can I do this.

Comment: I can connect to my database of Joomla. but the problem is that password field in database is encrypt. I don't know how I can check the password that user fill in asp.net application with Joomla password.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.geekgumbo.com/2010/07/02/use-joomla-login-credentials-outside-of-joomla/

This website has a login script using the following:

```
//Change these to your Joomla details
$dbhostname = 'localhost';
$dbusername = 'root';
$dbpassword = 'password';
$dbdatabase = 'joomla15';

// Get these from your form...
$username_for_check = 'admin';
$password_for_check = 'admin';

$joomla_user;
$joomla_pass;
$joomla_salt;

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhostname,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbdatabase);

if ($result = $mysqli->query('SELECT j.username,j.password FROM joomla15.jos_users j WHERE j.username="'.$username_for_check.'" LIMIT 1;')) {

  if ($result->num_rows == 0){
      echo 'Username does not exist.';
  }else{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
      $joomla_user = $row->username;

      $pass_array = explode(':',$row->password);
      $joomla_pass = $pass_array[0];
      $joomla_salt = $pass_array[1];
    }

    if($joomla_pass == md5($password_for_check.$joomla_salt)){
      echo 'Username and password combination validated.';
    }else{
      echo 'Invalid password for username.';
    }
  }
} else {
  echo 'LOGIN VALIDATION: MySQL Error - '.$mysqli->error;
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [Central Authentication Service who called CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service) solution for this problem.

Joomla has some plugin for CAS and many article exists for explain how to use CAS in C# ASP .NET.

this Joomla plugin may be helped. [External Login](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication-external/5366).

but my big problem is when any body login in Joomla site I want to automatically login in ASP.NET site and I don't know what do am I do for this problem. for more detail you can see [How to share Joomla login session from one joomla website to one ASP.Net MVC website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319451/how-to-share-joomla-login-session-from-one-joomla-website-to-one-asp-net-mvc-web)