# How to share Joomla login session from one joomla website to one ASP.Net MVC website

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, joomla

I have one Joomla site and another web app which is ASP.NET MVC based. I am wishing to do auto login to another app after login to Joomla website.

For example is it possible that after a successful login in Joomla website, automatically issue a new request to this ASP based app with User ID and password ( encrypted of course ) embedded in query string. Then this ASP application would take that information and decrypt the password and perform auto login?

Here's [How to use web services to share Joomla login session from one website to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19542084/1539100) a example for one Joomla site with another Joomla site.

I hope to see code example for explain solution.

Comment: I want to some example code from both side (Joomla and ASP.NET MVC).

Comment: Updated my answer to add example PHP/Joomla plugin code, and link to an example of PHP code to login to ASP from PHP

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with  ASP .NET MVC, but you can intercept the Joomla login event by referring to [Creating a Plugin for Joomla](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla).  It can be a *very* simple [User Plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User), with which you will have access to many events, particularly `OnUserLogin` and `OnUserAfterLogin`.  The code you put in either of those two events is where you'd use CURL, or whatever other technology, to POST your ASP request.

Very basic code structure:

```
<?php 
defined('_JEXEC') or die; 
class Plgtest extends JPlugin {   
    public function onUserLogin($user, $options = array()) {
        // The user has now logged into Joomla - all user info is available in variable $user
        // Do some PHP stuff here to "issue a new request to this ASP based app"
        // Example PHP code for ASP login at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539787/how-to-post-asp-net-login-form-using-php-curl
    } 
} 
?>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539787/how-to-post-asp-net-login-form-using-php-curl) for the PHP code to login to ASP from PHP.

Comment: thank you for your response, it is useful for Joomla side but unfortunately my bigger problem in ASP.NET MVC side.

Comment: Once logged into Joomla, what has to "happen" on the ASP side? You said "automatically issue a new request to this ASP based app" - do you know how to do that in PHP?

Comment: Not exactly, because at first I don't know exactly ASP based app wants from me and second I am not expert in PHP. but I have some guess from those links.

Comment: We can't possibly guess what your ASP app needs - I believe the answer gives you the code you requested - its up to you to adapt it to what your project/apps require.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Joomla or ASP.NET, but I think the easiest way to do this is by storing the sessions in common place. This could be a database which both systems can access and read the session data from.

This solutions relies on the fact that one of the websites exists as a subdomain of the other or the cookie which the systems share cannot be read by both. Check this link for another solution working around this restriction. It is a messy solution, but possible.

[Cookie restriction workaround (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370495/share-a-cookie-between-two-websites)

As I said I don't know either frameworks, but I would imagine you would have to tinker with the way sessions are read/written to in both systems.

Hope this can help you in the right direction.

Best regards.